# how to set max time of 2mb of image to be uploaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

fileName = $_FILES['uploaded']['name']; 
        $this->tmpName = $_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name']; 
        if( !$this->isWritable() ) 
        { 
            die( "Sorry, you must CHMOD your upload target to 777!" ); 
        } 
        if( !$this->checkExt() ) 
        { 
            die( "Sorry, you can not upload this filetype!" ); 
        } 
        if( !$this->checkSize() ) 
        { 
            die( "Sorry, the file you have attempted to upload is too large!" ); 
        } 
        if( $this->fileExists() ) 
        { 
            die( "Sorry, this file already exists on our servers!" ); 
        } 
        if( $this->uploadIt() ) 
        { 
            echo "success";
          echo "Your file has been uploaded!
Click uploadTarget . time() . $this->fileName . "\">here to view your file!"; 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            echo "Sorry, your file could not be uploaded for some unknown reason!"; 
        } 
    } 

    public function uploadIt() 
    { 
        return ( move_uploaded_file( $this->tmpName, $this->uploadTarget . time() . $this->fileName ) ? true : false ); 
    } 

    public function checkSize() 
    { 
        return ( ( filesize( $this->tmpName ) > $this->maxSize ) ? false:true ); 
    } 

    public function getExt() 
    { 
        return strtolower( substr( $this->fileName, strpos( $this->fileName, "." ), strlen( $this->fileName ) - 1 ) ); 
    } 

    public function checkExt() 
    { 
        return ( in_array( $this->getExt(), $this->exts ) ? true : false ); 
    } 

    public function isWritable() 
    { 
        return ( is_writable( $this->uploadTarget ) ); 
    } 

    public function fileExists() 
    { 
        return ( file_exists( $this->uploadTarget . time() . $this->fileName ) ); 
    } 
} 
$img = new imgUploader(); 

?>

Comment: Add more details on the OP.

Comment: MB is not a unit of time.

Comment: i have edited you question please edit it so we can help you and please include only what you think is helpful and think about it in other ways 
the problem is (how to change the maximum size of uploaded image ) then write what you have tried and what error you get